# I need some customisation in full join of Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have df1 like :[image]

df2 like:[image]

MyCode:

```
data1=[('16','123456','SuryaAndCo','FY2022Q2','12'),
       ('16','1234567','SuryaAndCo','FY2022Q2','11'),
       ('16','12345678','SuryaAndCo','FY2022Q2','19'),
       ('17','23456','BabJiAndCo','FY2021Q1','2'),
       ('17','2345689','BabJiAndCo','FY2021Q1','12'),
       ('18','23445','SalBhai','FY2023Q1','11'),]


data2=[('16','123456','SuryaAndCo','FY2022Q2','22'),
       ('16','1234567','SuryaAndCo','FY2022Q2','222'),
       ('16','12345678','SuryaAndCo','FY2022Q2','33'),
       ('17','23456','BabJiAndCo','FY2021Q1','44'),
       ('17','2345644','BabJiAndCo','FY2021Q1','55'),
       ('19','23445','SalBhai','FY2023Q1','77'),]


df1=spark.createDataFrame(data1,['Org','Item Number','Supplier','FiscalPeriod','QtyL'])
df2=spark.createDataFrame(data2,['Org','Item Number','Supplier','FiscalPeriod','QtyR'])
fulldf=df1.join(df2,on=['Supplier','Item Number','FiscalPeriod'],how='full')
display(fulldf)
```

Output to above code:[image]

Here you can see the Org has Nulls on both left and right table columns,even though if i drop right or left Org column,that will be anyway giving me one null.But the actual output should be like:[image]

Here you can see there are no nulls in Org Code,How to achieve this type of Full Join.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fulldf = df1.join(df2,on=['Supplier','Item Number','FiscalPeriod'],how='full').
      withColumn('Org1',coalesce(df1['Org'],df2['Org'])).
      drop(df1['Org']).
      drop(df2['Org']).
      withColumnRenamed('Org1','Org')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).